# Does there exist a uniform distribution on the set of all permutations of a countably infinite set?

Tags: measure-theory, permutations, uniform-distribution

For a finite set $N = \{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$, a permutation over $N$ is a bijective function $\pi: N \to N$. A uniform distribution over the set of all permutations of $N$ must assign each permutation $\pi$ with the same probability $\frac{1}{n!}$.

For a countably infinite set, say, the set of all natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, a permutation is also a bijective function $\pi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist a uniform distribution on the set of all permutations of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: There can never be a uniform distribution on a set with infinitely many elements because their probabilities would need to sum to 1. Is this what you’re asking?

Comment: @AlexR. Implicit in your essentially correct observation: ... for which individual points have positive probability. Else the uniform distribution on $[0.1]$ qualifies.

Comment: @AlexR. There are uncountably infinite permutations of $\mathbb{N}$.  So even thought each permutation is assigned zero probability, the integral over all permutation may still be 1, which doesn't violate countable additivity.

Comment: What does uniform mean here? What condition must a measure satisfy to be uniform?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure